# Symfony dynamic model form template

Tags: forms, dynamic, symfony1, field

I am developing symfony based web application. I have many Models (Laptop, Netbook, Ipad,Tablet.... all these models **inherited** from Product model).Based on these models I also have Forms (LaptopForm, NetbookForm...so on).
In my action class I get Model name and assign it to template :

```
 $modelForm = $this->modelName.'Form';

 $this->form = new $modelForm();
```

Then in my template I do that `<?php echo $form ?>` ..There is no problem it prints all fields and labels in html table.

But my problem is that I want to divide template in to 2 parts. General and special fieldset.In general fields set i want to display Product model fields(name,price...).But Special field set changes according to product type. How I can handle this special fields set?Can someone give a clue or source please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it manually, in your specialized form class (not alter the base class).
Perhaps, with the use of sfWidgetFormSchema :
http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/A-Widgets#chapter_a_sfwidgetformschema
You have to name the widget 'general' and 'special', for a stanhdard re-use in form template, like this :

```
<?php echo $form['general'] ?>
<?php echo $form['special'] ?>
```

Comment: thanks for answer.it is very helpful. I have one more question. When I generate these models from command line, base class fields are automatically set to "$this->setWidgets(...)". Can I configure symfony so that automatically created model fields are set to "$general=sfWidgetFormSchema(array('name'=> new fWidgetFormInputText(),...)"..Thanks

Comment: I am affraid that it's not possible. But, maybe you can try something with the inheritence system in the class Productform wich must be inherited in other form like desktop...